# Multiple widgets: Launching configuration activity on widget click

Tags: android

following scenario:
I have 3 of the same widgets on my home screen. If one gets clicked, the widget configuration activity gets launched.

This was implemented by following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetConfigurator.class);
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId); 
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_linearlayout, pendIntent);
```

The launching is working, but there is one problem:
1. Widget A gets clicked, configuration activity of Widget A is opened
2. User hits "back" key, configuration activity disappears
3. Widget B gets clicked, configuration activity of Widget B is opened
4. User hits "back" key
=> Now the configuration activity of Widget A is shown

I always only want the "actual" configuration activity (fitting to the widget that was clicked) to be shown. Which settings do i have to use for the Intent / PendingIntent?

thx for any help

Answer (score 3):

Seems after trying around a lot i now found a working solution for all android versions:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_linearlayout, pendIntent);
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your pending intent code to include the widget id as android reuses intents. I wasted many hours on this with the wrong intent being sent on click.

```
PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, WIDGETID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to get sure your current activity gets closed is to call finish(). An android app is build like stack, the activity A starts, if the user hits back, this activity isn´t closing. It´s just lying under the new started activity B. If user hits back in activity B, then activity A will be shown. I never tried this, but if You call finish in your onBackPressed method, the current activity will be closed. To do this, override onBackPressed in your Activitys.